# SQL Update on same table and Preventing Duplicates

Tags: sql

I am trying to update the values on a table which might have duplicates and I want to avoid those duplicates to avoid the errors:

**Table:**

```
TicketID : UserID
  0      :   1
  0      :   5
  0      :   6
  1      :   4
  1      :   5
```

What I am trying to do is update all the Ticket Id's `that = 0,` to the value of `1`. As you can see there is already a value of `1 : 5` which causes the conflict. I have tried `merge, insert into` with `where` and I can not get a query that ignores updating rows that will potentially exist.

After the update I would manually delete the remaining `0 : 5` since that would not of been updated, I thought merge could do that for me but I could not get that to work

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: MS SQL Server, I am going to try Pirion method

Answer (score 1):

Check for duplicates first and delete them - and then perform the ubdate.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM Table
WHERE TicketID = 0 AND UserID IN(SELECT UserID FROM TABLE WHERE TicketID=1);

UPDATE TABLE
SET TicketID = 1
WHERE TicketID = 0;

/*If no error run*/
COMMIT TRAN
/*If error run*/
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. It will help you..

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET TicketID = 1
WHERE TicketID = 0 AND UserID Not IN(SELECT distinct UserID FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE TicketID=1)

DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE TicketID = 0
```